# How to get click event of table row/ table item?

Tags: android, row, android-tablelayout

I have a simple table layout in the .xml file. I am adding components to it at run-time.
Following is my code:

```
public class Home extends Activity{

    TextView tv1; int i;TableRow tbrow;
    String [] names = {"First Name","Last Name", "Title","Company","Phone"};
    int [] images = { R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.star2,R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon}


        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        TableLayout ll=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);


        TableRow trow=new TableRow(this);
        ImageView Image1=new ImageView(this);
        ImageView Image2=new ImageView(this);
        ImageView Image3=new ImageView(this);
        ImageView Image4=new ImageView(this);
        tv1=new TextView(this);
        trow.setClickable(true);

        Image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
        Image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star2);
        Image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
        Image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);

        tv1.setText("Brochures");
        trow.addView(Image1);
        trow.addView(tv1);
        trow.addView(Image2);
        trow.addView(Image3);
        trow.addView(Image4);
        trow.setId(0);
        ll.addView(trow);
        for(i=1;i<5;i++){
            tbrow=new TableRow(this);
            ImageView img1=new ImageView(this);
            tv1=new TextView(this);
            CheckBox chk=new CheckBox(this);
            ImageView img2=new ImageView(this);
            ImageView img3=new ImageView(this);
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pdf);
            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
            img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);

            tv1.setText(""+names[i]);
            tbrow.addView(img1);
            tbrow.addView(tv1);
            tbrow.addView(chk);
            tbrow.addView(img2);
            tbrow.addView(img3);
            tbrow.setId(i);
            Log.e("TAG", "ID: "+tbrow.getId());
            tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                      
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, ""+tbrow.getId(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("TAG", " clicked ID: "+tbrow.getId());
                }
            });
         ll.addView(tbrow);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I click on any of the rows, the `onClick()` event of the last row is triggered. Instead of text view, I also tried to trigger the `onClick()` event for table row, but in vain.

I want to know which row is clicked. `getID()`, `setID()` won't work.

Please help.

Comment: did you try OnClickListener for table row @pallavi

Comment: `tbrow.setOnClickListener(...);` toasts `4` when i try to click any row.

Comment: But I want the 1st row to be like the fixed row and the the other rows would contain values. 
List 1st row contains the column names and other rows contain the column data. This is not possible in Grid right?
1st row as constant?

Comment: You wrote: "tbrow.setOnClickListener(...); toasts 4 when i try to click any row.". This means the listener works, so you only have to find the error in your `onClick` code that do the same job for all the rows.

Comment: yes, the `onClick` is triggered, but not for the respective table row or text view.

Comment: problem solved!!! Instead of declaring the `TableRow` as a global variable, I just made it local and `final`!!! 
DONE!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the line

> tbrow=new TableRow(this);

to

```
final TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
```

and it will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks a LOT!!! I didn't know 1 word would make that much of difference!!! it's solved!!! just needed to write `final` instead of making it global variable... Thanks @ernazm